# Combine Saml2 and oAuth2 in the same authentication module

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, saml-2.0

I have developed an authentication module in spring-boot based on spring-security that allowed user authentication via oAuth2 to external systems such as AAD, ADFS ...

Everything works correctly but a new client requests the use of Saml2 as an integration protocol.

Currently the module consists of the following parts

SecurityConfig.java

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .cors()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .formLogin()
            .disable()
            .httpBasic()
            .disable()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(new RestAuthenticationEntryPoint())
            .and()
            // only allow access to specified URIs
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/auth/**", "/oauth2/**", "/public/**")
            .permitAll()
            // only allow access with fully authenticated requests
            .anyRequest()
            .fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
            // configure OAuth2 login
            .oauth2Login()
            // configure token endpoint for hack
            .tokenEndpoint()
            .accessTokenResponseClient(getAccessTokenResponseClient())
            .and()
            // endpoint for authorization (the endpoint we expose and knows the third party to go to)
            .authorizationEndpoint()
            .baseUri(OAUTH2_AUTHORIZE_BASE_URI)
            .authorizationRequestResolver(oauth2AuthorizationRequestResolver)
            .authorizationRequestRepository(httpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository)
            .and()
            // endpoint for callback (where the third party service calls back after authenticating a user)
            .redirectionEndpoint()
            .baseUri("/oauth2/callback/*")
            .and()
            // the service to use
            .userInfoEndpoint()
            .userService(customOAuth2UserService)
            .and()
            .successHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler)
            .failureHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler);

    // Add our custom Token based authentication filter
    http.addFilterBefore(tokenAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

Application.yaml

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          example1:
            clientId: -----------------
            clientSecret: -----------------
            redirectUriTemplate: -----------------
            grant-type: authorization_code
            authorizationGrantType: authorization_code
            tokenName: code
            authenticationScheme: query
            clientAuthenticationScheme: form
          example2:
            clientId: -----------------
            clientSecret: -----------------
            tenant-id: -----------------
            active-directory-groups: -----------------
            redirectUriTemplate: -----------------
            grant-type: authorization_code
            authorizationGrantType: authorization_code
            tokenName: code
            authenticationScheme: query
            clientAuthenticationScheme: form
```

My doubts regarding the integration with Saml2 are the following:

1. It is possible to combine both authentications in the same application, could you have something like this in Application.yaml?

```
spring:
  security:
    saml2:
      relyingparty:
        registration:
          aad: 
            identityprovider:
              entity-id: -----------------
              verification.credentials:
                - certificate-location: "classpath:certs/aad.cert"
              singlesignon.url: -----------------
              singlesignon.sign-request: false
          okta:
            identityprovider:
              entity-id: -----------------
              verification.credentials:
                - certificate-location: "classpath:certs/okta.cert"
              singlesignon.url: -----------------
              singlesignon.sign-request: false
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          example1:
            clientId: -----------------
            clientSecret: -----------------
            redirectUriTemplate: -----------------
            grant-type: authorization_code
            authorizationGrantType: authorization_code
            tokenName: code
            authenticationScheme: query
            clientAuthenticationScheme: form
          example2:
            clientId: -----------------
            clientSecret: -----------------
            tenant-id: -----------------
            active-directory-groups: -----------------
            redirectUriTemplate: -----------------
            grant-type: authorization_code
            authorizationGrantType: authorization_code
            tokenName: code
            authenticationScheme: query
            clientAuthenticationScheme: form
```

2. If the previous configuration is possible, how would it be represented in "SecurityConfig.java -> configure (HttpSecurity http)"? Is it possible to enter saml2Login in the current configuration?
3. I have seen some incomplete examples where they talk about the use of "authenticationProvider" to implement this type of case. Does anyone know if this is effective?

```
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
          auth.authenticationProvider(oauth2AuthenticationProvider());
          auth.authenticationProvider(saml2AuthenticationProvider());
          auth.authenticationProvider(DDBBAuthenticationProvider());
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

1. A key thing to a for is that your apps shouldn't need to know anything about SAML, as an old technology. You will want your UIs and APIs to be modern and use OAuth tokens.
2. Can't answer this one.
3. Sounds like you should be using an Authorization Server (AS) rather than doing too much in your own authentication module. Third party systems have built in support for many providers and have taken years to develop.

As an example see [all of these options](https://curity.io/product/authentication-service) supported by the Curity product, which has a free community edition that you can download.

In terms of the general pattern:

- Your apps speak OAuth and OpenID Connect and interact with the AS
- If a business partner wants to use SAML logins against their own Identity Provider, you only need to make SAML config changes in the AS - with zero code changes to your apps